# Do these plastic molds exist?

Tags: concrete, construction, slab, cement, pavers

I want to make a few concrete pavers, so I started looking for a few tutorials, and found this [youtube video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jqrbOd5sNZY).

In the tutorial, he uses a plastic mold where he pours the concrete. Something like this:
[image]

Do these plastic molds exist? I searched amazon and home depot, but didn’t find anything.

Comment: Just like concrete stamping molds and edge molds, you're going to have to go to a decorative concrete supply store, and some of them are more friendly to the public than others.  Also be warned that these molds are heavy duty and expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the recommendation of a neighbor, I purchased a set of five molds for US$99 with free shipping. The size for my bundle was 10" x 18" x 1.5" but they have many different sizes available. The [web site](https://www.themoldstore.us/) has been upgraded since I purchased. The molds appear to be high quality and my neighbor has nearly paved his entire yard with the casting he's done.